# Does WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync do a post or a get

Tags: c#, webclient

I have seen WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync doing a GET, can I do a POST by using this method, for HTTP request?

Comment: From MSDN "For an HTTP resource, the GET method is used" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138334(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET`.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138334(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method uses the RETR command to download an FTP resource. For an HTTP resource, the GET method is used.

There is an [`UploadDataTaskAsync` that lets you control the verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138382(v=vs.110).aspx); [else it defaults to `POST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138525(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method uses the STOR command to upload an FTP resource. For an HTTP resource, the POST method is used.

Comment: Yeah, alright, but my situation allows me use only HTTP.

Comment: So the solution is to use UploadDataTaskAsync(either GET or POST) and monitor the downloaded file by using the event UploadDataCompleted. It is strange but it works!

Answer (score 1):

You use the UploadString method to POST with the WebClient:

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

Comment: I am talking about the WebClient method DownloadDataTaskAsync alone. With explanation from @JonSkeet I understand it is a GET Method.

Answer (score 1):

Method documentation says that "This method uses the RETR command to download an FTP resource. For an HTTP resource, the GET method is used."

[link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/hh138334(v=vs.110).aspx)